# When to use PHP self::class? When to use __CLASS__?

Tags: php, rector

### Preamble

I'm working on a legacy Open Source project supporting PHP 5.5 to PHP 8.3.

### Question

My question is simple:

1. When to use PHP `self::class`?
2. When to use `__CLASS__`?
3. Does it may change from PHP version to version? (at least interested after PHP 5.5)

NOTE: You can skip the other sections. It's just a description of why I am here and what I tried.

### Documentation

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

It seems it does not mention changes between them.

### Tests

I tried to do define some tests (feel free to suggest more):

```
<?php
/**
 * This is just a test class
 */
class A {
        public function selfclass_normal() {
                return self::class;
        }
        public function constclass_normal() {
                return self::class;
        }
        public static function selfclass_static() {
                return self::class;
        }
        public static function constclass_static() {
             return __CLASS__;
        }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {
        public function selfclass_normal() {
                return self::class;
        }
        public function constclass_normal() {
                return self::class;
        }
        public static function selfclass_static() {
                return self::class;
        }
        public static function constclass_static() {
             return __CLASS__;
        }
}

echo "Normal class:\n";
$a = new A();
echo $a->selfclass_normal();
echo $a->constclass_normal();
echo A::selfclass_static();
echo A::constclass_static();
echo "\n\n";

echo "Empty extended class\n";
$b = new B();
echo $b->selfclass_normal();
echo $b->constclass_normal();
echo B::selfclass_static();
echo B::constclass_static();
echo "\n\n";

echo "Extended class rewriting methods\n";
$c = new C();
echo $c->selfclass_normal();
echo $c->constclass_normal();
echo C::selfclass_static();
echo C::constclass_static();
echo "\n\n";
```

This is the output on PHP 7.4:

```
Normal class:
AAAA

Empty extended class
AAAA

Extended class rewriting methods
CCCC
```

So I'm inclined to think that `self::class` and `__CLASS__` are the same.

### Exploring it in Rector.php

I discovered that Rector.php has a rule to convert `__CLASS__` to `self::class` and not the vice-versa.

https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#classconstanttoselfclassrector

So it seems Rector prefers `self::class`.

Does it help in understanding the historical differences between `self::class` and `__CLASS__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it may change from PHP version to version? (at least interested after PHP 5.5)

`self::class` should be the replacement of `__CLASS__` [in design](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars#considerations) and more flexible. Unfortunately, if you are still using php 5, you may encounter some bugs (e.g. [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65419), [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70957)), but if you are using php 7 or later, it will be OK.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of the potential issues of `self::class` in PHP < 7

Comment: Also maybe additional question, is there any difference between static::class?

Comment: If relevant I may update the question to mention that in an explicit way

Comment: Yes, https://3v4l.org/uQB1c

Answer (score 1):

`__CLASS__` can only used in class context while `::class` can be used anywhere like `A::class` to get the FQN of a class.
You normally use `::class` for simplicity because it works everywhere.